# Equivalent to i2c_adapter_quirks in Linux kernel 3.18

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Is there an equivalent to the i2c_adapter_quirks struct in kernel 3.18? I am trying to implement an i2c bus driver that has a maximum read and write length.

Answer (score 2):

There's no equivalent. `i2c_adapter_quirks` was introduced in version 4.1 of the kernel; the patches are very clean so it should be possible to backport the patch series, starting with [2187f03a9576](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=2187f03a9576c4fb8342deed912b5ba6fcf98cba) and [b7f625840267](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=b7f625840267b18ef1011cba0085bb7e237d76f7).

Comment: Just a nit: nowadays if someone refers to upstream commit ID it would be 12+ most significant digits from a hash.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko So, taking [this](https://lkml.org/lkml/2010/10/28/287) and [this](https://plus.google.com/+LinusTorvalds/posts/hbdxizBNrYn) into account, 12 digits should be enough up to kernel v26, so we have another 20 years before increasing it to 13 :)